# Set servlet init parameters in application.properties

Tags: servlets, quarkus

I have my servlet init parameter defined in the servlet

```
@WebServlet(
        urlPatterns = {"/*"},
        initParams = {@WebInitParam(name = "targetUri", value = "http://my host:10040")})
public class WebOption extends ProxyServlet {
```

I want to set this in the application.properties
Can an example and url to the docs be provided?

Comment: After inspection of the servlet I'm extending, I determined that I could override a method to set the init parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspection of the servlet I'm extending, I determined that I could override a method to set the init parameter